# Word to describe the case-sensitivity of a word

Tags: capitalization, camel-case

This question is very related with software development. I would like to know if there is a word to refer the way that a word is written.

For example somebody has written "HasChildren" for a variable name while the correct way should be "hasChildren".

I could tell this person: "you should write hasChildren instead of HasChildren".

But if I want to be more polite I would say something like "the way you use the lower and capital letters in HasChildren is incorrect, it should be hasChildren".

What I want is to have a term to replace "*the way you use the lower and capital letters*". Does that word exist? I am not sure if *capitalization* would work.

Comment: You've tagged the question as 'camel case', is there any reason for not using that term? Most developers will be familiar with it - "please use camel case for your variable names"

Comment: How you word it, or if it's your job, is up to you. A shorter word for capitalization is *case*: "The case that's standard is 'hasChildren' without the initial cap." Developers are not delicate flowers.

Comment: @KillingTime camelCase would work in the example but what I want is a way is something more generic to describe the way in which each letter in a phrase takes capital or lower case.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I know developers are not delicated and I am sure Linus Torvalds would consider this concern ridiculous if not delusional but what I want is to see if it exists in English a word equivalent to "the way that letters are written in lower or upper case".

Comment: I commented Linus Torvalds  because he is famous for yielling in his code reviews :)

Comment: When MS Word needs to know if a replacement search needs to match the case as entered in the before& after fields, it offers the choice of **Match case**.

Comment: Or StudlyCaps. Like grammar rules, spelling, punctuation, and capitalization rules are so thick on the ground that they all contradict one another. The result is everyone does what they please, unless they can force others to do it instead. Take your pick; nobody cares except locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word **casing** is used in computing with this meaning. [Wiktionary defines it as:](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/casing)

> (*uncountable, computing*) The state of letter case across a whole phrase or whole lines of text; the collective state/arrangement of uppercase and lowercase letters.

It gives the following example:

> *The replacement string should have the same casing as the matched text.*